# Unable to port forward properly

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I am trying to set up RDP access to my development machine, since I am planning to travel. I have done port forwarding in the past, but could not get it to work on my new router. After configuring Virtual Server, and forwarding an external port number to internal port 3389, I can RDP using the public IP while connected to the network, but when I try to use the same IP from a different out of network computer, it does not work.

I also have a Huawei E5573s 4G portable router that I use with a different service provide, and had successfully hosted websites in the past while using Windows 7. When connected to my computer in USB mode, it would let me port forward an external port to internal port 80 and I could browse websites on my laptop. However not only am I not able to open a test webpage from an out of network computer, I am not even able to use the public IP and port to open a website from the same computer where I have port forwarded.

In both the above scenario, I do not have a fixed IP, but use the service from noip.com. In any event, it should at least work with a known temporary IP address.

In addition, on both the scenarios, I see a different IP address number while looking at:

1) the router's WAN status/device info

2) the whatsmyip.com

3) the NoIP DUC tool

...in other words three different IP Addresses.

How can I get my actual accurate IP Address and what is the simplest and cheapest way to get RDP access from public internet. I am running Windows 10 and have ensured that the firewall is allowing ports 80 & 3389, and Windows Defender is the only firewall that I have.

Comment: Your question is very confusing without any information of real use... But my guess is you are behind an Enterprise Grade NAT and do not have a "public IP" address that is dedicated to your use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: @acejavelin What is confusing about the question, I'll try to clear it. Actually, I am behind a home internet connection. I have two ISPs. One is a cable connection via a fixed router and the other is a 4G Mobile connection through a portable dongle.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart it is a traditional IPv4 address. The IP address in the Router shows up as 172.16.xx.xx and whatismyip.com shows it as 103.59.xx.xx

Comment: 172.16.xx.xx is what is showing as the WAN IP Address. My router's gateway is 192.168.0.1 and I have fixed my computer's IP to 192.168.0.150. I tried port forwarding as well as setting that IP to the DMZ feature. Still neither option worked. This is so confusing since I have done port forwarding many times in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your "WAN" address of 172.16.X.X is a private IP address, it doesn't appear you're are in control of inbound port forwarding as you do not have an exclusive public IP address that is assigned to you (your router) either statically or dynamically.

In other words, your carrier is doing NAT already and you cannot port forward from the public IP because you are not in control of it.

The corrective action here would be to contact your ISP and request a public IP address, which may or may not incur an additional monthly fee and possibly a setup fee as well.

Comment: Upvoted, since I had a feeling it had to do with my ISP and you explained why. What about the second part of the question. i.e. with my second ISP via portable router. I had done port forwarding on that in the past while on Windows 7. However, unlike the first router, where typing http://172.16.X.X:5555 would forward and open a test webpage, the same does not happen on the second.

Comment: @ShahidThaika Most likely your ISP issued public IPs at that time, and does not do that now (this is becoming a more common practice due to constraints on IPv4 addresses worldwide). It could also be that your second ISP did not have client isolation in their network, so for example a router with 172.16.12.75 could talk to 172.16.111.94 without issues within their network and they now don't allow that. Without knowing more about the conditions at that time it is hard to say for certain.

Comment: @ShahidThaika Also, because it is not clear at what point in the network you are trying to open the webpage from (inside or outside the local LAN), this could relate to either how the ISP or your router handles a "loopback" to itself if you were testing from inside your LAN. Some will redirect back to you, and others will reject these packets, this could be the router or the ISP.